# Scope of variables and the digits function

Tags: syntax, scope, julia

My question is twofold:

1) As far as I understand, constructs like for loops introduce scope blocks, however I'm having some trouble with a variable that is define outside of said construct. The following code depicts an attempt to extract digits from a number and place them in an array.

```
n = 654068
l = length(n)
a = Int64[]
for i in 1:(l-1)
    temp = n/10^(l-i)
    if temp < 1 #  ith digit is 0
        a = push!(a,0)
    else # ith digit is != 0
        push!(a,floor(temp))
        # update n
        n = n - a[i]*10^(l-i)
    end
end
# last digit
push!(a,n)
```

The code executes fine, but when I look at the `a` array I get this result

```
julia> a
0-element Array{Int64,1}
```

I thought that anything that goes on inside the for loop is invisible to the outside, unless I'm operating on variables defined outside the for loop. Moreover, I thought that by using the `!` syntax I would operate directly on `a`, this does not seem to be the case. Would be grateful if anyone can explain to me how this works :)

2) Second question is about syntex used when explaining functions. There is apparently a function called digits that extracts digits from a number and puts them in an array, using the help function I get

```
julia> help(digits)
Base.digits(n[, base][, pad])
   Returns an array of the digits of "n" in the given base,
   optionally padded with zeros to a specified size. More significant
   digits are at higher indexes, such that "n ==
   sum([digits[k]*base^(k-1) for k=1:length(digits)])".
```

Can anyone explain to me how to interpret the information given about functions in Julia. How am I to interpret `digits(n[, base][, pad])`? How does one correctly call the digits function? I can't be like this: `digits(40125[, 10])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce you result, running your code gives me

```
julia> a
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 654068
```

There's a few mistakes and inefficiencies in the code:

- `length(n)` doesn't give the number of digits in `n`, but always returns 1 (currently, numbers are iterable, and return a sequence that only contain one number; itself). So the for loop is never run.
- `/` between integers does floating point division. For extracting digits, you´re better off with `div(x,y)`, which does integer division.
- There's no reason to write `a = push!(a,x)`, since `push!` modifies `a` in place. So it will be equivalent to writing `push!(a,x); a = a`.
- There's no reason to digits that are zero specially, they are handled just fine by the general case.

Your description of scoping in Julia seems to be correct, I think that it is the above which is giving you trouble.

You could use something like

```
n = 654068
a = Int64[]
while n != 0
    push!(a, n % 10)
    n = div(n, 10)
end
reverse!(a)
```

This loop extracts the digits in opposite order to avoid having to figure out the number of digits in advance, and uses the modulus operator `%` to extract the least significant digit. It then uses `reverse!` to get them in the order you wanted, which should be pretty efficient.

About the documentation for `digits`, `[, base]` just means that `base` is an optional parameter. The description should probably be `digits(n[, base[, pad]])`, since it's not possible to specify `pad` unless you specify `base`. Also note that `digits` will return the least significant digit first, what we get if we remove the `reverse!` from the code above.

Comment: Wow, how embarrassing so many mistakes in so few lines of code :p But thank you very much for clearing that up for me, your code worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this cheating?:

```
n = 654068
nstr = string(n)
a = map((x) -> x |> string |> int , collect(nstr))
```

outputs:

```
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
6
5
4
0
6
8
```

Comment: I'd say not cheating but not very efficient. It works though!

Comment: I decided to do a quick check and yeah, @StefanKarpinski, that version seems about an order of magnitude slower than Toivo's version, but changing the mapped function to `(c) -> c - '0'` gets it up to basically the same speed :) I assumed `string(::Int)` would be pretty fast though (even while handling a few more cases...) - [not sure who we have to thank for that...](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blame/master/base/intfuncs.jl) ; )